# Change a character from a 'char' in c++

Tags: c++, replace, char

Is there a way to change a single character in a char?
like this example
I have user input. The user should enter a number. If the number is float or double the user should enter a point. But if the User enters ',' (3,44 or 54,33)
my code doesn't work. Is there a general way to change the comma to point?
Like this:

```
char number1[50], number2[50];

number1 = 2,33;
number2 = 54,45;
```

turns into

```
number1 = 2.33;
number2= 54.34;
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: sure.  `number` is an array of characters so write to the correct place in the array: `char number[50] = "2,33"; number[1] = '.';`

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to compile with or without the missing `;`. Please expand on your true goal.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: pineapple, we definitely need a better problem description and code example.

Comment: If on the other hand you do want to assign a number directly to a string, then that's what sprintf() is for (or a stringstream if you are using C++)

Comment: I edit my question, I hope my issue description is better.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can not assign an int, double etc. to a char array.
So `number[50] = 2,33;` is meaningless.
You have to define the number as "array of char". What I mean? You should define the char array as `char number[50] = "2,33";`

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
char number[50] = "2,33";
number[1] = '.';
std::cout << number << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output should be: 2.33

Comment: ok I need this for user input and if the user enters, for example, the number 52,3 I need to change the ',' to '.'.

Comment: So you have to search for ',' in the char array. In modern C++ you can use just string for that. But if you want to manipulate whole array by yourself. You can use for loop and check each of the element of the array. When you find the position of the ',' you just stop and get the position. Then change the value of the number[position] as '.'

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char valor;
  const char x = ',';
  const char y = '.';

  cout << "Please enter an char value: ";
  cin >> valor;

  /*Cast char to string*/
    std::stringstream auxiliar;
    std::string varfin;
    auxiliar << valor;
    auxiliar >> varfin;

  /*Replace*/
  std::replace(varfin.begin(), varfin.end(), x, y);
  std::cout << varfin;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Cast char to string for work methods of replace

[image]

Methods for replace

[image]

Comment: Text should be presented as text. There are [many, many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) why images should not be used in questions and answers unless the image being an image is important to the question or answer.

Comment: Hi. Excuse me. I did not know.

Comment: Easily fixed, so you might as well do it. I'd love to get the downvote back. I hate leaving them around where kids could find them.